# Help removing duplicate part from this question

Tags: discussion

Later part of this question [How does the superpower distribution of Asgardians work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83808/how-does-the-superpower-distribution-of-asgardians-work) contains this question in a sense: [Can Bifrost Bridge be operated without Heimdall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/can-bifrost-bridge-be-operated-without-heimdall)

How to remove the duplicate part from the first question without removing the example?

Or, can both questions coexist?

Comment: I applied an edit to cut back the focus on Heimdall and the Bifrost. I think you should ask that second question separately, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd just scrub the entire last paragraph. It doesn't really add anything to the master question which is about how Asgardians get and hone their powers.

If you're utterly wedded to the idea of keeping the example, you could improve it by including more examples; extending it to other gods and their known powers (e.g. can other god-level Asgardians learn to create illusions or use the Odinforce?) and just remove the reference to the bifrost bridge.

Comment: For the record, this probably would have been better asked in the chatroom. Questions about improving questions always get a quick and fulsome response.

Comment: Which question should have been asked in the chatroom?

Comment: @SS - I''m not saying that you can't ask "how should I improve" questions in Meta, I was merely remarking that you'd probably get just as good (and probably better) response if you asked it in the chatroom